# How to provide a local path for downloading a file from a server?

Tags: php, html, download

I am trying to download an object/ file from AWS S3 to the local computer.  I would like to provide the user with the opportunity to provide the local path.  In HTML we have the

```
<form> and <input type="file">
```

elements to provide the user with the option to select a file from the file system for upload.  How do we do the reverse?  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Being able to do so would risk websites trying to put stuff in `/etc/hosts`, `~/.bash_profile`, `C:\Windows\System32`, etc. You can set a (suggested) filename, but it's going to go to the browser's preferred `Downloads` folder.

Answer (score 1):

It's a security issue to write anywhere you want to the filesystem. You can present it as a download (application/octet-stream / Content-Disposition) but the user's browser gets the right to choose in the end regardless.

You can *force a file to download instead of display on a page* from the server with a specific filename only, but it stops there. The browser has the choice of popping up a Save As dialog or saving it in the default Downloads folder.

[image: Firefox download settings]

Incidentally, when a user chooses to upload a file, you don't actually get the *path* either - you get a fake path and a user-defined real filename. On Windows Chrome, it sends something typically like `c:\fakepath\` so it doesn't reveal overly-personal information in the path.

Comment: if i am using php, what would be the downloads folder path be?

Comment: There is none. It is chosen entirely by the client that wants to download it. You have absolutely zero say in it. Think about the way that you yourself would want to be treated: why would you want any random website to overwrite files of their choice on your hard drive anywhere?